# Not sure why im getting variable not defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a variable not defined compile error right when my code begins and I'm not sure why. I declared the variable as a double, then attempted to assign the value of a cell on a specific worksheet to that variable. Anyone know why this is not working?
Thanks.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub trial()
    Dim incentivebeta As Double
    Dim intercept As Double
    Dim agebeta As Double
    Dim x As Double

    incentivebeta = wsLogisticRegression.Range("B3").Value
    intercept = wsLogisticRegression.Range("C3").Value
    agebeta = wsLogisticRegression.Range("D3").Value

    x = incentivebeta
End Sub
```

Comment: well `wsLogisticRegression` is not a recognized worksheet, you do not declare it or set it.

Comment: thanks that helped. I see what i was doing wrong